# Reset sequence value as 1

Tags: postgresql

I need that after `TRUNCATE` table, reset his sequence, for this I do :

```
SELECT setval('mytable_id_seq', 1)
```

After, when insert rows in table, sequence is started from `2`  not `1`

How to resert sequence value such, that new first value will be `1`?

```
 SELECT setval('mytable_id_seq', 0) // gives error that value is out of range
```

Comment: IIRC there is an optional third argument. Truncate also has an RESET option, which affects the sequence. Better check The Fine Manual.

Comment: Thanks, `restart identity` helps me

Comment: The `Easiest Way` is to drop the sequence and run the create query, which you have earlier used to create the same sequence.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

First set the minimum value of the sequence

```
alter sequence mytable_id_seq minvalue 0 start with 1;
```

Now either reset it:

```
SELECT setval('mytable_id_seq', 0)
```

Or reset it while truncating:

```
truncate mytable restart identity;
```

Comment: `setval()` will actually reject the value of 0, because it's out of bounds. (Hence OP's question.) It should be `setval(seq, 1, false)` instead to mark it as unused.

Comment: @Denis That why the `minvalue` in the `alter sequence`.

Comment: `restart identity` is the best option IMHO.

Comment: This modify the sequence definition which is a non-necessary side-effect. `setval()` third argument or `TRUNCATE`'s `RESTART IDENTITY` definitely are the way to go.

Comment: if you're using CASCADE syntax is:  truncate mytable restart identity CASCADE;

Answer (score 7):

Either use the third argument for `setval()`:

`setval(yourseq, 1, false)`

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-sequence.html

Or alter the sequence:

```
alter sequence yourseq restart
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altersequence.html