# ALTER postgreSQL sequence

Tags: postgresql, sequence, restart, alter

I am quite very new to postgreSQL. I am have a sequence which starts from 1 by default. What I am looking for is that if I want to move my next value, which is now 87, to 2000. I am unable to do that. Can any one suggest me how to go about doing the change?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reset sequence value as 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16485708/reset-sequence-value-as-1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ALTER the sequence using the following code:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE seq_name RESTART 2000.
```

I request you to please go through the postgres SQL manuals.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altersequence.html

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try this out. And surely go through the manuals.