# Altering default sequence when I don't know its name

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to increment sequence on id of table. But I don't know sequence name because it's default sequence that postgresql generated.

I have read questions like these:
[ALTER postgreSQL sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26037186/alter-postgresql-sequence)
but they don't really answer my question because I don't know name of sequence. I tried:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE table_name_id_seq INCREMENT BY 1;
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: To increment a sequence you need to use `nextval()` not  `alter sequence` - what exactly are you trying to do there? Sync the sequence with the values in the column?

Comment: I have read about it in postgres documentation but how do you use it with default sequence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retreive the name of the sequence from the table/column names.

Then you can use `setval` to set the current value. In the example below, it sets the value to the biggest found value (next one will be +1)

```
SELECT setval(
  pg_get_serial_sequence('myschema.mytable','mycolumn'), 
  max(mycolumn))
FROM myschema.mytable;
```